# How to memoize in parent object of ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, memoization

How do i memoize an expensive query in parent object and reuse it in child objects? The problem i'm facing is that each time i make a reference from child to parent: child1.parent or child2.parent, it gives different object ids and memoization does not happen.

```
class Post
  has_many :comments
  def total_comments
    unless @total_comments
      puts "Loading comments"
      @total_comments = comments.count
    end
    @total_comments
  end
end

class Comment
  belongs_to :post
  def total_comments
    post.total_comments
  end
end

post.comments[0].total_comments
post.comments[1].total_comments
```

This should've queried for comments only once, but because it's not memoized on the same object it's loading twice

```
Loading comments...
Loading comments...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Several ways to do it:

**1. Use [ActiveRecord Association Extensions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions)**

```
class Post
  has_many :comments do

      def total
          proxy_association.target.size
      end

  end
end
```

Allows you to call `proxy_association` object, and appends the method to the instance of `comments` (so you can call `@post.comments.total`)

---

**2. Use [`:inverse_of`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)**

```
#app/models/post.rb
Class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments, inverse_of: :post
end

#app/models/comment.rb
Class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post, inverse_of: :comments
end
```

Allows you to reference parent object from `self` (`self.post.total_comments`)

---

**3. Use "Eager Loading" (keeping objects in memory)**

This is query-level, and alluded to in NitinJ's answer & [this RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/181-include-vs-joins):

```
Post.includes(:comments)
```

I think NitinJ's comments are better than mine here, as I only have experience in creating DB calls with `.includes` (not using it in an association capacity)

---

**BONUS - [Counter-Cache](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column)** -- use this instead of `comments.count` - it stores the count in memory, which will remove an expensive DB call!

Answer (score 1):

Try this post =`Post.last(include: :comments)` this statement eager loads the relation now perform operation `post.comments[0]` this will not trigger any `SQL` query to find that as the associated records is already there